# Load Class library dll in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, class-library

I have made a C# Class Library that has some NuGet packages installed in it, like Azure.Core.

When the library has been compiled, I get my library as a MyLibrary.dll which is all fine.
The only files that are in the output folder is the MyLibrary.dll, MyLibaby.deps.json and MyLibrary.pdb - nothing else.

Now I need to load this in Powershell by using:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\MyLibrary.dll"
```

And this adds it fine and I can see my methods by using the `Get-Member`.

When the code then starts running, I get an error saying:

> 'Azure.Core, Version=1.37.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Have I done something wrong with the way I have done my class library or am I doing the Powershell bit wrong? As I mentioned, I don't have any more .dll files other than MyLibrary.dll

The Class Library was made in .NET Core 7.0, if that info is needed

Comment: "When the library has been compiled" how did you do that? Just compile from the CLI or Visual Studio? Did you `publish` it?

Comment: I complied it via Visual Studio. I have not published it, as it is only going to be used for internal tools

Comment: If you publish it, the output directory should have all the dependent DLL files needed for the application to run.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That did the trick!
Was not aware of this :) Thank you!

Comment: @wads you can also avoid this headache altogether by enabling "Produce single file" in your publish settings so that the dependents get bundled alongside your DLL

Comment: @TP95 I don't see an option to "Produce single file", so I don't think it's applicable in my case

Comment: @wads Are you sure? Check the visual studio tab in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs#publish-a-single-file-app). It's a checkbox you can enable in the publish settings (its kind of hidden away).

Comment: @TP95 Yes, I checked the link beforehand and saw the option, but it is not available for me. Not sure if it's because my project is a Class Library and not an application

Comment: @wads that option is only available if the project is `Self-contained` instead of `Framework dependant`. You can check that by going your project's `Properties` folder and opening the publish profile that ends with `.pubxml`. See if that file has `<SelfContained>` as true.